# Как включить ЧПУ для YII2 если я использую встроенный docker образ?

Tags: yii2

Установил YII2. Шаблон Advenced. Там есть файл docker-compose. Пробежался по нему. Это специальный образ от yii для разработки. Запустил. Дальше, включаю urlManager

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
    ],
],
```

то есть убираю комменты с этого куска в конфиге (они по дефолту были). Ожидаю, что у меня будут работать нормальные урлы. Но теперь при редиректе на любую страницу я получаю 404. Может какой то htaccess надо прописать? Или как включить стандартный образ для разработки с нормальными урлами? Еще хотел бы странный префикс `site` в урлах убрать. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Ага, вот эта статейка помогла! [ссылка](https://xn--d1acnqm.xn--j1amh/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8/htaccess-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-yii2-basic) 
Не понимаю, почему так костыльно то? Зачем какие: то префиксы `site`, зачем что то конфигурировать? Почему просто нельзя взять и начать работать, как в случае с тем же Laravel. Ну да ладно, спасибо за внимание)